# Rspec matcher for random number in a hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to fix a test, but because we run the tests randomly, the `change_requests` end up being random, so the expected hash in the before do block always ends up failing.

Error Example:

```
    Diff:
       @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
       -:change_requests => [0, 0],
       +:change_requests => [23, 24],
```

Test:

```rb
    let(:expected_hash) do
      {
        from_admin_user: user.first_name,
        station_id: station.id,
        ten_minutes_before_reminder: false,
        one_hour_after_reminder: false,
        change_requests: [0, 0],
        one: requests[0][:new_price],
        two: 'NO CHANGE',
        three: 'NO CHANGE',
        four: requests[1][:new_price],
        price_change_at_time: nil
      }

    end

    before do
      expect(PriceChangeService).to receive(:new) do |hash|
        expect(hash).to eq expected_hash
        price_change_service
      end
    end
```

Is there away to solve this by, for example, adding a random number matcher somehow to the `change_requests` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the random key with:

```
expect(hash.except(:change_requests )).to eq 
  expected_hash.except(:change_requests)
```

Or stub the method which generates `change_requests` to make it deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of `change_requests` is a dynamic one, we basically need to check two things:

1) `change_requests` is an array which contains two elements

2) The rest of the hash, apart from `change_requests` is as expected (Here, change_requests is removed from the expected_hash declaration)

We could achieve this by using the `reject` method on the newly created `PriceChangeService` object to check all keys and values EXCEPT `change_requests`. Additionally, we would need to check the `change_requests` value as mentioned in point (1).

This could be done as follows:

```
before do
  expect(PriceChangeService).to receive(:new) do |hash|
    expect(hash.reject{|k, v| k == : change_requests}).to eq(expected_hash)
    expect(hash[:change_requests].class).to eq(Array)
    expect(hash[:change_requests].length).to eq(2)
    price_change_service
  end
end
```

You could additionally check for the type of elements that are being expected as well.